# Calculating cdf from a piecewise pdf

Tags: probability

Hi I am working on a homework problem and I derived on a solution wich I think/hope is correct. I include a picture below. I tried to make it work with MathJax but no luck...sorry for that....I have a piecewise CDF and I shall calculate the pdf. I know that I have to take the derivative.
But where my problem starts is that that in the formula $$x-x^2/8-1$$ the integral of the pdf from 0 to 2 is included so i have to substract that first, don’t I. (I did that in my calculations below).
If I do that it does not matter in the end because it becomes a constant, and the derivative of a constant is $0$ , but how do I write that down? I cant just forget about it..

I hope it somehow makes sense.... [image]

Comment: Given that CDF, indeed the $-1$ from the third piece of the CDF does not enter into the third piece of the PDF. You do however need to be careful to check that the CDF is actually continuous in the first place, but it will turn out that it is.

Comment: @Ian, thanks is my reasoning correct, i don’t really get what you mean, if you calculate the cdf its P(X<x) so there is the probability from 0<x<2 included. Or am i just somehow totally wrong.

Comment: It looks correct. Yes, the probability between 0 and 2 is included, but that doesn't break anything. You still get that piece of the density by taking the derivative of the corresponding piece of the CDF, even though the CDF "knows" about the previous piece. (Indeed, consider going from your PDF to your CDF. Integrating the second piece would result in $x-x^2/8+C$; how would you evaluate $C$?)

Comment: @Ian That’s 0 , I actually wrote tha above. I was just unsure about my logic behind it. Many thanks

Comment: No, the $C$ is $-1$ so that $F(2)$ has the correct value.